# This question may already have an answer?

Tags: support, questions, exact-duplicates

I have just seen the below auto-generated markup for the first time:

[image]

Unlike other auto-generated markup, this isn't edited into the question and appears to be in-page rather than in-post. The post in question has close votes for 'duplicate' - I'm aware that some work has gone into the closing as duplicate stuff recently, is this an additional side effect of this as I have never seen this before?

To get one of these added to a question do you simply need to VTC it as a duplicate or are there any other actions that are required to get one of these to appear?

Comment: I believe this is part of the new closing questions changes.  There are big changes to most aspects of the closing process.  However, I can't really find documentation at the moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, this banner appears as soon as one close as duplicate vote is cast. There is a [discussion on Meta.SO on whether this behaviour makes sense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166427/151385), as requiring only one vote could be abused relatively easily.

Comment: Ok cool, well at least that link highlights something else - whatever is making our head text in the notification orange could perhaps be changed to make it not orange? :p~